# How can I calculate recall and precision if I have 4 x and y values in two dataset?

Tags: python, precision-recall

I have two dataset(ground truth and predicted) and both have xmin, ymin,xmax and ymax values. I found some source codes but they are only for x and y values not 4 values. You can find the source code here. How can i change it to four values. Are there any idea?

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#create dataset with 5 predictor variables
X, y = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                                    n_features=4,
                                    n_informative=3,
                                    n_redundant=1,
                                    random_state=0)

#split dataset into training and testing set
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=.3,random_state=0)

#fit logistic regression model to dataset
classifier = LogisticRegression()
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

#use logistic regression model to make predictions
y_score = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)[:, 1]

#calculate precision and recall
precision, recall, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_test, y_score)

#create precision recall curve
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(recall, precision, color='purple')

#add axis labels to plot
ax.set_title('Precision-Recall Curve')
ax.set_ylabel('Precision')
ax.set_xlabel('Recall')

#display plot
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can split the data into two parts and solve the problem without trying a specific set up ?

For each dataset you can split into :

**Min analysis :** *Xmin, Ymin ==> you run the code on it*

**Max analysis :** *Xmax, Ymax ==> you run the code on it*

If the problem is that you need multiple Y targets you have documentation on that : [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html).

Hope it helps !

Comment: but first dataset: xmin,ymin, xmax,ymax and second dataset: xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax. Both of the dataset have these. how can  split then? I have to do it for both dataset @bvittrant

Comment: You can split each into two you'll have 4 analysis in the end ?

Comment: Will it work if even these are rectangle coordinates? @bvittrant

Comment: it will change nothing till you have a numeric target (y) and a bunch of features (X) trying to explain your target. But what are you trying to predict ? What are the features you want ot use to predict this target ?

Comment: I work on object detection model and I have bounding boxes for both ground truth and predicted models. I would like to plot precision and recall curve@bvittrant

Comment: But what is the nature of the target ? Because precision and recall apply only to categorical targets. Im' confused because you use Min/Max name but it means you're talking about numerical features ?